# Export Database connection to Oracle Developer

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a database Connection established in odbcad and Microsoft Access (aswell as working in Excel) via ODBC and want to also get it working in Oracle SQL developer.

It is a Windows SQL Server as far as i know and I have tried several Settings, of which None works. I have also installed Driver for ODBC. I would like to Import Settings into SQL developer as applied in MS Access, is there any possibility?

Answer (score 0):

No, SQL Developer is a Java application and uses a JDBC driver.

But if you look at the odbc properties for your connection, those should largely translate to what you need to define a basic connection.

Oracle:
Server name or IP address of the DB, port # for the listener, and the name of the SID or Service, plus a valid username and password is all you need to connect to Oracle.

What error do you get when you try to connect?

Show us what you're trying.

Update: 
You're trying to connect to SQL Server but you're getting"

```
Native SSPI library not loaded
```

You're trying to use OS Authentication for your connection. For this to work with the jTDS driver, you need to copy a DLL file named ntlmauth.dll (which is for NT authentication) under the jtds-x.x.x-dist\x86\SSO\ or jtds-x.x.x-dist\x64\SSO\, to any directories in the PATH environment.

Please update your question such that's it's clear you're connecting to SQL Server and share the error message so others can find it.

I imagine this question is a duplicate of many previous iterations of the same challenge.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. I am getting various different error Messages which all do not seem trustworthy. The Problem is, the ip adress of the host is fine, also the port is what I think okay, but the SID is unknown to me. Again this is not a Oracle SQL Server, but a MS SQL Server which I am trying to connect to. The error Messages are mostly related to Java not beeing found. I tried 2 jre's and a jdk in which the Java.exe is missing to be put down in the config file of SQL developer.

Comment: The most reliable error message seems to be: Native SSPI library not loaded. check Java.library.path

Comment: @Nuke i updated my answer, now please update your question :)